# Find smallest difference between dates SAS

Tags: date, sas

I have this HW question that is asking me:

**Write a SAS Program to creates a data set that contains test date closest to 
        delivery date. Your program must work for any test date and delivery date.**

Here is what I have done so far. The data sources are in seprate sheets in excel which I p pulled in and merged and there is only 1 deliver date and 21 test dates. I figure the best way to find the closest day was the absolute value of the smallest difference, then use proc sort because that is the only proc command we are allowed to use other than proc import and export. Any ideas/help/whatever would be appreciated thanks.

```
proc import datafile = "C:\Users\file1.xls"
dbms=xls replace out=labs; sheet = "labs";;
run;

proc import datafile = "C:\Users\file1.xls"
dbms=xls replace out=delivery; sheet = "delivery";
run;

data dl;
merge delivery labs;
dd = delivery_date;
diff = dd - Test_date;
run;
```

Here is the data they are both in 1 column didn't know how to format that here.

Sheet 1:

delivery_date
11/16/2011

Sheet 2:

Test_date
13-Mar-11
10-Apr-11
20-May-11
9-Jun-11
31-Jul-11
17-Aug-11
12-Sep-11
10-Nov-11
11-Oct-11
12-Dec-11
29-Feb-12
13-Mar-13
10-Apr-10
20-May-10
9-Jun-10
21-Jul-11
15-Aug-11
15-Sep-11
19-Oct-11
21-Nov-11
22-Dec-11

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: Sounds like your teacher is a masochist, only allowing you to use `proc sort/import/export`. It would be nice if we could see a sample of your data set (i.e. a subset of the excel file that you're working with). My guess is that in every row, you have one deliver date and at least 21 test dates and you want to figure out which test date is closest to the deliver date on each row?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are on the right track. Given that this is homework, I'm not going to give you a complete solution, but here are some components you may find helpful:

- First, you should look at the SAS website for more information about the absolute function (since that is the route you want to take):
  [SAS/IML(R) 9.3 User's Guide: ABS Function](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/imlug/64248/HTML/default/viewer.htm#imlug_langref_sect024.htm)
- Next, you may want to review the documentation for [PROC SORT](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/65145/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1nd17xr6wof4sn19zkmid81p926.htm). It will be useful for finding the *smallest* difference.
- For getting only one record, you may find the [OBS](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/ledsoptsref/63326/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0h5nwbig8mobbn1u0dwtdo0c0a0.htm) Data Set Option helpful.
  (Hint: you may need to create a second dataset.)